# How to make active a link on an entire picture although there's already another link in a part of it?

Tags: html, css

I've got a tile containing a title, a category, a link to the category, a picture and a global link to the picture. As it is, this global link is only active in a piece of the picture area. I would like it to be global.

Here is the HTML :

```
<div id="article">
<div class="block-module">
<a class="view-full-module" href="http://www.cosmos.com/Common/Images/Destinations/machupicchu3.jpg">
<img class="image" src="http://www.cosmos.com/Common/Images/Destinations/machupicchu3.jpg"/>
</a>
     <div class="block-about">
        <h2 class="block-title">Title</h2>
        <span class="block-stats"><a href="" class="author-link">Category</a> Date</span>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS :

```
.view-full-module { cursor: pointer; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(31, 32, 33, 0); width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.image { width: 100%; }
.block-module { width: 100%; position:relative; margin:0; padding:0; cursor:pointer; border-radius:10px; z-index:4; }
.block-about { position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; padding:4em 1em 1em 1em; background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.55), rgba(0,0,0,0.8)); background-image:linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.55), rgba(0,0,0,0.8)); }
.block-about a { position:relative; z-index:5; }
.block-title { max-width:100%; margin:0 0 0; color: white !important;font-size:1.625em; }
.block-stats { width:100%; margin-top:0.35714em; font-size:0.875em; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.55) !important; }
.author-link { color:#659dae; }
#article { top:0; margin: 0; padding:20px; -moz-column-gap: 20px; -webkit-column-gap: 20px; column-gap: 20px; -moz-column-width: 260px; -webkit-column-width: 260px; column-width: 260px; }
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5qwejk20/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the element `.block-about`.

In doing so, you can essentially click *through* the element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/x4axgdom/)

```
.block-about {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Browser support for the `pointer-events` property can be [found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

---

Another option would be to move the anchor element and then absolutely position it *relative* to the parent in order to take the full dimensions.

The reason you need to move the anchor element in the DOM is because if it wraps the `img` element, then you can't have your background fading at the bottom since the anchor needs to be positioned *above* it in order for the click event to work anywhere within the element.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jfqfbopo/)

```
.view-full-module {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```
<div id="article">
    <div class="block-module">
        <img class="image" src="http://www.cosmos.com/Common/Images/Destinations/machupicchu3.jpg" />
        <div class="block-about">
             <h2 class="block-title">Title</h2>
 <span class="block-stats"><a href="" class="author-link">Category</a> Date</span>

        </div>
        <a class="view-full-module" href="http://www.cosmos.com/Common/Images/Destinations/machupicchu3.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

As a side note, you may want to add `vertical-align: top` to the `img` element in order to remove the gap under it.

[**Example without the gap**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgvr1w63/)

```
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there an alternative for IE10 (maybe IE9) ?